# Converting SharePoint date (not datetime) field to do math with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to capture a date on a SharePoint edit form.. then take that date and subtract that date  from it to get a value for the number of days. Is this a complicated process or something simple? I'm not having much luck searching due to super secure (and unnecessary) security blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to acheive this and is pretty simple. For eg: see below how to get difference between today and created date of a list item using Jquery.

```
var submissionDate = new Date(oListItem.get_item('Created'));
var today = new Date();
var diff = today - submissionDate;
var days = parseInt(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the number of dates difference using jQuery in 1 edit form. This is simple.

- dump jQuery js file and your javascript code file in a asset library somewhere
- edit the edit form using designer and add 1 line: the reference to your javascript code file (that references jQuery) under the PlaceHolderMain
- in your javascript code file use a jQuery selector to get the date, do the javascript subtraction and use jQuery to insert the difference in dates in the dom of the form (or ... if you want to update an existing list column with the value for number of days take a look at spservices)

  The above solution because your tags are "javascript". Other ways that might be a solution (though I don't know the content of your problem):
- use a calculated column to hold the difference in dates
- use a workflow to do something with that date